# Cutout of application by notch

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

My application is cut off from the top side by the notch 
Is there any specific solution to overcome this problem.
I am using the emulator Pixel 3 XL API 27

[image for illustrstion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muo8l.png)

What should I do any code is there to increase the height of the top bar or status bar or should I increase the height of the title bar, but the title bar is still cut off
Any suggestion or code explanation

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout

Answer (score -1):

Try below solution

It is get size of notch as per device and set margin top to view So,it's fit in all device.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    this.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main);

    /*------------ Check display cutout size and give top margin to toolbar -------------*/
    setMarginTopAccordingDisplayCutout(context, yourTopMainView, convertDpToPixel(34), 0);
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    ...
    //your Code
 }

private void setMarginTopAccordingDisplayCutout(Context context, View view, int extraTopWithoutCutout, int extraTopWithCutout) {
    int statusBarHeight = 0;
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        statusBarHeight = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    if (statusBarHeight > convertDpToPixel(24)) {
        final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams[] layoutParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams[1];
        layoutParams[0] = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams[0].topMargin = statusBarHeight + extraTopWithCutout;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams[0]);
        //topbarlp.setMargins(0, statusBarHeight, 0, 0);
        //Set above layout params to your layout which was getting cut because of notch
        ///topbar.setLayoutParams(topbarlp)
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate statusBarHeight :: " + statusBarHeight);
    } else {
        final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams[] layoutParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams[1];
        layoutParams[0] = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams[0].topMargin = extraTopWithoutCutout;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams[0]);
    }
}

private int convertDpToPixel(float dp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return Math.round(px);
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through a similar approach but haven't got fruitful result

Comment: @SyedHuzaifa What is issue generated?

Comment: Your method calling line isn't invoking, can you give more specifications?

Comment: @SyedHuzaifa I am currently use this method and it's working well.Please check in live device.

Comment: Are you add full screen support?

Comment: '

/*------------ Check display cutout size and give top margin to toolbar -------------*/
setMarginTopAccordingDisplayCutout(context, binding.toolbar, convertDpToPixel(34), getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen._5sdp));
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

'



this line of code is not working

Comment: Where should be this line of code will go.....means in which section this line of code is going to be handled

Comment: in OnCreate method

Comment: Can you explain binding.toolbar and R.dimen._5sdp in the method calling

Comment: Pass 0 instead of getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen._5sdp) it is value of extra margin.If you want to give extra margin top(cutout size + extra margin) and binding.toolbar is topView in your layout.

Comment: binding.toolbar is not invoking in the parameter

Comment: What is DataBindingUtil? What is the datatype of binding

Comment: This is DataBinding don't see this only add answer code into given position.